# How to create the frequency of a column and then perform an aggregation on that data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate, stringr

**Objective:**

I have a dataset, df, that I wish to first tally up the number of occurrences for each date and then multiply the output by a certain number.

```
Sent                      Duration   Length

1/7/2020  8:11:00 PM       34         216
1/22/2020 7:51:05 AM      432         111
1/7/2020  1:35:08 AM       57          90
1/22/2020 3:43:26 AM       22         212
1/22/2020 4:00:00 AM       55         500
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
Date                     Count          Aggregation(80)
1/7/2020                 2              160
1/22/2020                3              240
```

I wish to count the number of times a particular 'datetime' occurs and then multiply this outcome by 80. The date, 1/7/2020 occurs twice, and the date of 1/22/2020, occurs three times. I am then multiplying this number count by the number 80.

**The dput is:**

```
structure(list(Sent = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/22/2020 3:43:26 AM", 
"1/22/2020 4:00:00 AM", "1/22/2020 7:51:05 PM", "1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", 
"1/7/2020 8:11:00 PM"), class = "factor"), Duration = c(34L, 
432L, 57L, 22L, 55L), length = c(216L, 111L, 90L, 212L, 500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
df1<- aggregate(df$Sent, by=list(Category= df$dSent), 
    FUN=length)
```

However, I need to output the frequency that the dates occurs along with the aggregation (multiply by 80)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: yes @Wimpel thank you, I have corrected this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` way of things..

**code**

```
library( data.table )
#set data as data.table
setDT(mydata)
#set timestamps as posix
mydata[, Sent := as.POSIXct( Sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p" ) ]
#summarise
mydata[, .(Count = .N, Aggregation = .N * 80), by = .(Date = as.Date(Sent) )]
```

**output**

```
#          Date Count Aggregation
# 1: 2020-01-07     2         160
# 2: 2020-01-22     3         240
```

Answer (score 3):

We can convert `Sent` to `POSIXct` format and extract the date, count the number of rows in each date and multiply it by 80. Using `dplyr`, we can do it as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(Date = as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(Sent))) %>%
 summarise(Count = n(), `Aggregation(80)` = Count * 80)

#  Date       Count `Aggregation(80)`
#  <date>     <int>             <dbl>
#1 2020-01-07     2               160
#2 2020-01-22     3               240
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `table`.

```
as.data.frame(cbind(Count=(r <- table(as.Date(df$Sent, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))), 
      Agg=r*80))
#            Count Agg
# 2020-01-07     2 160
# 2020-01-22     3 240
```

or

```
`rownames<-`(as.data.frame(cbind(Count=(r <- table(as.Date(df$Sent, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))), 
                    Agg=r*80, Date=names(r)))[c(3, 1:2)], NULL)
#         Date Count Agg
# 1 2020-01-07     2 160
# 2 2020-01-22     3 240
```